# Linear mappings

Tags: linear-algebra

The mapping $S:P^2 \to  P^2$ is given by $S(p(x)) = p(x) + x$. Show that it isn't a linear mapping.

$P^2$ is the vector space of the quadratic polynomials $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2$

I'm stuck with the $'+x '$ bit.

Comment: A map $T:V \to W$ needs to satisfy two conditions in order to be a linear mapping.  Can you verify those conditions?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the $'+x'4 bit"?  I'm not sure if that's standard notation across all courses/books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

$$\begin{align}&S(x+1)=(x+1)+x=2x+1\\{}\\
&S(x)+S(1)=x+x+1+x=3x+1\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow, I suck. I must have asked this and either seen the answers and not responded, or just never looked back again. I don't even remember having to solve the problem! Thanks for your answer :) I upvoted but I don't have enough reputation for it to show

Answer (score 2):

$S(0) = 0+x \neq 0$. Thus it can't be linear.

Comment: I wrote this is wrong and **I** was wrong: it is right, of course. +1

Comment: Wow, I suck. I must have asked this and either seen the answers and not responded, or just never looked back again. I don't even remember having to solve the problem! Thanks for your answer :) I upvoted but I don't have enough reputation for it to show

Answer (score 0):

What is $S(0)$?  What must $S(0)$ be if $S$ is linear?